# How do I define constructor in service and factory in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

i am little bit familiar with angular. still on learning process. working with ng version 1.4.8. so i like to know how could i define constructor function in service and factory.

here is one sample service .now tell me how to define constructor in service or factory ?

```
angular.module('myApp').service('helloService',function($timeout){
  this.sayHello=function(name){
    $timeout(function(){
      alert('Hello '+name);
    },2000);
  }
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('TestController',
  function(helloService){
  helloService.sayHello('AngularJS'); // Alerts Hello AngularJS
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to define a constructor in a service?

Comment: i am learning angular. so bit curious to know is it possible or not. so please drive me to right direction if possible.

Comment: I was about to write you an answer, but @Vladimir Zdenek's one is pretty good, have a look at it.

Comment: does this example code try to prove service is singleton.........check this sample and let me know https://codepen.io/rajMrPerfect/pen/mwPYXQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you pass to `.service` gets called with `new`, thus it is already basically a constructor. It is a "constructor function" and it implicitly returns an object, which is the singleton:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('helloService',function($timeout){
  // This constructor function implicitly returns an object. It is called
  // only once by Angular to create a singleton.

  this.sayHello = function(name) {
    // etc
  }
});
```

Just to illustrate, if you passed an ES6 class to `.service` (which does have a constructor) instead of a constructor function, that constructor would be called when the singleton is created:

```
class HelloService {
    constructor($timeout) {
        // Called once when the singleton is created
    }

     sayHello(name) {
         // etc
     }
}

angular.module('myApp').service('helloService', HelloService);
```

Using `.factory` is similar, but it doesn't get called with `new`. So the function you use in this case has to return a singleton object explicitly:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('helloService',function($timeout){
  // This factory function explicitly returns an object. It is called
  // only once by Angular to create a singleton.

  return {
      sayHello: function(name) {
          // etc
      }
  };
});
```

**Edit**: As mentioned by `@Vladimir Zdenek`, these "constructors" cannot be used to configure the singleton externally. However, I interpreted the question to mean "Where can I put code that runs when the singleton is created?". Singletons may need to initialize data, so that initialization can go in the "constructor".

Comment: tell me factory and service both is singleton in nature ?

Comment: Yes only once instance is created and shared across the app

Comment: when we are working with angular v1+ with ES5 then there is no way to declare ctor in service......am i right? then how can i say service is singleton in nature. can you please come with a example which tell me service is singleton.

Comment: Whether you pass Angular a constructor function or a class, Angular is still only going to call it once to create the singleton. If you want to support older browsers then you cannot use classes unless you transpile down to ES5 (which will basically convert the class into a constructor function).

Comment: I do not agree with your solution. As much as you created a constructor for service/factory, you cannot really use it to "configure" the singleton before it is create. Which I believe is the only good reason why to have a constructor for a singleton in the first place. Just because something can be done does not mean it should.

Comment: @Vladimir Zdenek I interpreted the question to mean "Where can I put code that runs when the singleton is created?". Thus if you are initializing pretty much anything, it can go in the "constructor". Even singletons may need to initialize some internal data. I did not see any mention of configuration in the question. Thus I do not believe I deserve the downvote.

Comment: Fair enough. Edit your answer so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: What additional information would you like in my answer? A clarification of why I answered this way even though the service cannot be configured?

Comment: I meant for you to make a really small edit because otherwise my downvote is locked and I cannot remove it. But I think it would make sense to mention that it cannot be used for a global config of the singleton.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that's how it works. I made an edit that mentions your concern. Also, I appreciate you telling me why I got the downvote!

Answer (score 3):

There is (probably in most cases) no need for a constructor when it comes to singletons. To require such a thing might be just pointing to a bad architectural design of your application.

That said, you can make a global configuration available for your service/factory by using a **provider**. You can find more on providers in the [Official Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe).

If you do not need a singleton and you wish to create a reusable piece of code, you can use something (in JavaScript) known as **factory functions**. You can see an example of such function below.

```
function MyFactory(myParams) {

    const Factory = {
        // Properties
        myProperty: myParams.myProperty,
        // Methods
        getMyProperty: getMyProperty
    };

    return Factory;

    function getMyProperty() {
        return Factory.myProperty;
    }

}

// usage
const myObj = MyFactory({ myProperty: 'Hello' });
```